# Removing a comment under a migrated question

Tags: discussion, comments, migration

I just commented a [SO question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471563/196312) asking the OP to rewrite his question in english (I didn't think of ru.SO at all, my bad).

Anyway, the question got migrated to ru.SO, making my comment totally irrelevant, of course. But I don't find any way to remove it.

Is there a way I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an account on [Stack Overflow in Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com).

Comments get dissociated upon migration because unlike posts, there is no UserId that can go in the UserId field in the comment row on that particular site. Only your UserDisplayName is copied over. There is a script that runs on migration to attribute comments of those who have *already* registered an account on the destination site, but if you don't already have an account there  on migration, there isn't enough information to retroactively re-associate your comment, unlike for posts.

I have an account there, so I went ahead and flagged your comment as obsolete. (Or I think I did, I clicked the middle flag option which is called Obsolete on English sites...)